# dataTable fnUpdate row with new value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, row

I am using datatables and have this `tr` element in `table`

```
<tr class="gradeA even row_selected" id="3692">
  <td class=" sorting_1">3692</td>
  <td class="">koza</td>
  <td class="" title="10:12:30">2013-12-31</td>
  <td class="">2014-02-06</td>
  <td class="">FULL packet</td>
  <td class="">NONE</td>
  <td class="">Name</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to update 1st and 4th `td` element using `fnUpdate` function. I have tried to update for only one `td` but it does not update.
In Chrome, console log I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_aData' of undefined

Here is what I have tried:

```
 // dynamically update row
 $('#example').dataTable().fnUpdate( ['Zebra'], parseInt('3692'));
```

`3692` is the id of the `td` element to know which row I need to update, and the `zebra` is the value to change. I know that I have not included which cell to update but I don't know how to do that. On datatables api, following example is given:

```
oTable.fnUpdate( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 1 ); // Row
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please review the docs here http://datatables.net/api

Your question is not complete, as you need to specify what column(td) you want to modify, but here's what I would try (assuming you want to update the second column).

`$('#example').dataTable().fnUpdate('Zebra' , $('tr#3692')[0], 1 );`

The second parameter will be the row, and the third is the column.

Note that I passed in a string.

Comment: `plus 1` for `second parameter will be the row, and the third is the column.`

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this:

```
var myDataTable= $('#myDataTableId').DataTable();
var row = myDataTable.row( '#idRow');
myDataTable.cell(row, 2).data("New Text").draw();
```

***Note:***

2 is column, cell inside modified row.

Comment: +1 becouse in some datatables versions (I don't know which ones) the `fnUpdate` is not supporter, and will result in error.

Comment: @baron_bartek I think that the functions that start with "fn" are deprecated in the new versions of datatables, but I don't know from which version this happens

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr').index(); // GET TABLE ROW NUMBER
$('#table').dataTable().fnUpdate('Zebra', [tableRow], 1, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the column. Your issue is that you are using row ID when the doc states that 2nd argument can be the aoData index or the element.

Make sure your number of columns is correct, but you should be able to do it like so:

```
 $('#example').dataTable().fnUpdate( ['Zebra'], $('#example tr#3692')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to update an entire row with data coming from backend as an object. Referring to:

```
$('#example').dataTable().fnUpdate('Zebra' , $('tr#3692')[0], 1);
```

I modified it a bit and used this lines of code to update an entire row without having to draw entire data table:

```
// get an selected row/row under edit action
let ele = $("#DTTableID")..dataTable().find('tr.row_selected');

$("#DTTableID").dataTable().fnUpdate(obj, ele);
```

Here `obj` is data object and `ele` is selected row.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable().fnUpdate(result, $('[data-id=' + idvalue + ']'), 8 );
```

This is best way to update column value without error and add table row with   `data-id="row id value"` ....it works fine.