# Update a row using DataTable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to know the correct way to update/redraw a table row using the new API. [Old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862476/datatable-fnupdate-row-with-new-value) suggest `table.fnUpdate`. Should I still be using the old API for this?

The [new API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/) tells me nothing about updating rows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try: `$(".dataTable").dataTable().row( index|selector ).draw()`?

Comment: I would presume that if there is no update in the new API, and you can get the old method to work, I would just use the old method.

Comment: I think it does! take a [look at this](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()).

Comment: @LShetty Ooh, thanks. Guess it didn't make sense to me to look under `data`...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently. I believe row().data() is what you are looking for https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.data%28%29

For example:

```
table.row( 0 ).data( newData ).draw();
```

---

Alternatively, you can use row().invalidate() https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.invalidate%28%29

```
var initialData = [new Data(), new Data()];
var table = $('#foo').Datatable({
  data: initialData
});
initialData[0].bar = 5;
table.row(0).invalidate().draw();
```

This is more useful if you are deriving your data from an external data source.

Comment: Followup question: Do you know how to make it trigger the existing `createdRow` event on the table?

Comment: createdRow is called on row creation, and that's it. There may be a way to trigger it if you search deep in the datatables source, but I think the better way is to use columnDefs. For example, check out the example here: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html. You can set a render function that will be called every time you update your table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would you mind showing me an example when `render` is triggered? It never fires in my tests...

Comment: Hmm seems I have to set `targets` in order for it to fire.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataTable').on('click', '.update', function () {
        var pageParamTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
        var tableRow = pageParamTable.row($(this).parents('tr'));
        var rData = [
            yourdata1,
            yourdata2,
            '<a href="#" data-href="1" class="update">Update</a>',
            '<a href="#" data-href="2" class="delete">Delete</a>'
        ];
        pageParamTable
                .row( tableRow )
                .data(rData)
                .draw();
    });
});
```

We are using this code our projects you can use this.

Comment: I am getting error `datatable.js:430 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_aData' of undefined
    at D.<anonymous> (datatable.js:430)
    at D.data (datatable.js:371)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (form1_datatable.html:194)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)`

Comment: I have also added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66447736/jquery-how-to-update-datatable-row-after-edit) regarding it

Answer (score 2):

if you have set specific id attribute for your rows with Datatable method ,
then you can select with :

```
table.row('#row_'+ idRow).data(rowData).draw()
```

Because generation of id attributes must be like this to be selected by after :

Ex id 3:

```
   // In php : push the key 'DT_RowId' foreach row  
      foreach ($items as $item) {
           $item['DT_RowId'] = 'row_' . $id;
      }
```

After you have specific id and you can select easily for an update :

```
 <tr id="row_3" class="...">
    ....
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Datatable</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Data</h1>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleDataModal" id="addDataButton">
            Add Random Data to Table
        </button>
        <div style="padding:20px 5px;">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                        <td>Support Engineer</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>37</td>
                        <td>2009/08/19</td>
                        <td>$139,575</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary update" data-id="0">
                                Update
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Thor Walton</td>
                        <td>Developer</td>
                        <td>New York</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2013/08/11</td>
                        <td>$98,540</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary update" data-id="1">
                                Update
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var counter = 1;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
        $('#addDataButton').on('click', function () {
                
            $('#example').DataTable().row.add( [
                'Juuso Temminen '+counter,
                'FrontEnd Engineer '+counter,
                'Riga ' +counter,
                '371 ' +counter ,
                '2021/3/3' +counter,
                '$123,23',
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary update" data-id="'+$('#example').DataTable().rows().count()+'">Update</button>'
            ] ).draw( false );
            counter++;

        });
        
        
        $('.table tr .update').click(function(){
            const id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var temp = $('#example').DataTable().row(id).data();
            temp[0] = 'Updated Datatable column '+ counter;
            $('#example').DataTable().row(id).data( temp ).draw(false);
            counter++;
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

there are new changes in Datatable I tried to create a demo page for you it is working locally I added insert and update example;
basically, I tried to understand the solution from Datatable page:  https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Answer (score 0):

**Update row in table.**

```
let updateRow = $("#tableId").DataTable().row(this)
tableRow.data([
  'text1',
  'text2',
  'text3',
  'text4',
])
```

**Add row in table.**

```
let updateRow = $("#tableId").DataTable()
tableRow.row
.add([
  'text1',
  'text2',
  'text3',
  'text4',
]).draw()
```