# jquery how to update datatable row after edit?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am trying to update my `datatable` when I edit some fields in my edit modal. Below is my `modal`, `add row` and `btnSubmit`  function to get the edited fields.

```
 <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Close</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name1" placeholder="Name">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="name">E-mail#:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="input-sm" id="email1" placeholder="Email">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Contact#:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm" id="cno1" placeholder="Contact">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="name">Date Of Birth:</label>
                    <input type="date" class="input-sm" id="dob1" placeholder="DOB">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnsubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>

$('.add-row').on('click', function() {
            name = $("#name").val();
            email = $("#email").val();
            cno = $("#cno").val();
            bdy = $("#bday").val();
            
            t.row.add([
                name,
                email,
                cno,
                bdy,
                "<button class ='btn btn-danger del'>Delete</button>" + " " + "<button class='btn btn-warning upd'>Edit</button>"





            ]).draw(false);
            $("#name").val('');
            $("#email").val('');
            $("#cno").val('');
            $("#bday").val('');

        });
        

$("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
                var new_name = $("#name1").val();
                var new_email = $("email1").val();
                var new_cno = $("#cno1").val();
                var new_dob = $("#dob1").val();
                
            
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
            })
```

**Update 1**

I have tried to make an array and then draw it.

```
//save change button click evnet
         $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();
            var tableRow = $(this).parents('tr');
            
                var new_name = $("#name1").val();
                var new_email = $("email1").val();
                var new_cno = $("#cno1").val();
                var new_dob = $("#dob1").val();
                var rData = [
                    
                        new_name,
                        new_email,
                        new_cno,
                        new_dob,
                        
                    
                ];
                table
                .row(tableRow)
                .data(rData)
                .draw();
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
            });
```

And now I am getting error

```
> datatable.js:430 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_aData' of undefined
  at D.<anonymous> (datatable.js:430)
    at D.data (datatable.js:371)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (form1_datatable.html:194)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

**Update 2**

So after doing some efforts I am finally able to update the row. But now I am getting an issue. Whenever I tried to update it, it always updates the 1st row. Below is my code for save button

```
//save change button click evnet
         $("#btnsubmit").on('click',function () {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();
            var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr');
            
                var new_name = $("#name1").val();
                var new_email = $("#email1").val();
                var new_cno = $("#cno1").val();
                var new_dob = $("#dob1").val();

                var rData = [
                    
                        new_name,
                        new_email,
                        new_cno,
                        new_dob,
                        "<button class ='btn btn-danger del'>Delete</button>" + " " + "<button class='btn btn-warning upd'>Edit</button>"
                    
                ];
                console.log(tableRow);
                 table
                 .row()
                 .data(rData)
                 .draw();
                 $("#myModal").modal("hide");
            });
```

**Update 3**

As per [Vahap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66453264/6854117) answer I updated my code

```
$('.add-row').on('click', function() {
            id = 0;
            name = $('#name').val();
            email = $('#email').val();
            cno = $('#cno').val();
            bdy = $('#bday').val();
            
            t.row.add([
                name,
                email,
                cno,
                bdy,
                '<button class ="btn btn-danger del">Delete</button>' + '' + '<button class="btn btn-warning upd" data-id="'+$('#example').DataTable().rows().count()+'">Edit</button>'





            ]).draw(false);
            $("#name").val('');
            $("#email").val('');
            $("#cno").val('');
            $("#bday").val('');

        });

//save change button click evnet
         $("#btnsubmit").on('click',function (e) {
             // Prevent event propagation
            e.stopPropagation();
            var new_name = $("#name1").val();
                var new_email = $("#email1").val();
                var new_cno = $("#cno1").val();
                var new_dob = $("#dob1").val();
              
            const id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            console.log(id);
            var temp = $('#example').DataTable().row(id).data();
            temp[0] = new_name;
            temp[1] = new_email;
            temp[2] = new_cno;
            temp[3] = new_dob;
            $('#example').DataTable().row(id).data( temp ).draw(false);
       
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
            });
```

But it still updating the 1st row always. Also I am getting `undefined` for `const id = $(this).attr("data-id"); console.log(id);`

I am able to add a new row, delete it and open a modal for editing it. Now I want to ask is that how can I set the updated values into my current `datatable` row? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: btnSubmit button is independent from table or having in each row? Problem seems to be finding right row to update values. `var tableRow = $(this).closest('tr');` gives only closest value to btnSubmit and always first,  how we know row that updated row?

Comment: @GökhanAldanmaz each row can be updated. So i guess we can work around using row id?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Datatable</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Data</h1>
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleDataModal" id="addDataButton">
            Add Random Data to Table
        </button>
        <div style="padding:20px 5px;">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                        <td>Support Engineer</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>37</td>
                        <td>2009/08/19</td>
                        <td>$139,575</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary update" data-id="0">
                                Update
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Thor Walton</td>
                        <td>Developer</td>
                        <td>New York</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2013/08/11</td>
                        <td>$98,540</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary update" data-id="1">
                                Update
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var counter = 1;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
        $('#addDataButton').on('click', function () {
                
            $('#example').DataTable().row.add( [
                'Juuso Temminen '+counter,
                'FrontEnd Engineer '+counter,
                'Riga ' +counter,
                '371 ' +counter ,
                '2021/3/3' +counter,
                '$123,23',
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary update" data-id="'+$('#example').DataTable().rows().count()+'">Update</button>'
            ] ).draw( false );
            counter++;

        });
        
        
        $('.table tr .update').click(function(){
            const id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var temp = $('#example').DataTable().row(id).data();
            temp[0] = 'Updated Datatable column '+ counter;
            $('#example').DataTable().row(id).data( temp ).draw(false);
            counter++;
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

there are new changes in Datatable I tried to create a demo page for you it is working locally I added insert and update example;
basically, I tried to understand the solution from Datatable page:  https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: It's creating a new row after i click on save button and adding `1` to every value

Comment: I don't want to create  a  new row all i want is to update the when i edit it ?

Comment: I edit the answer with an update example basically it is the same with the insert you need to find row-id and update with data you want

Comment: I have tried your code but it still updating the 1st row always. I have updated my question you can see it