# Replace entire row data and refresh

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have generated a datatable based on a datasource like below. I would like to replace an element which is representing a row, then force the row to re-render with the new data.

My problem is that I can only make it work when editing row properties. But when I replace the entire row, it doesn't work. Is it because datatables needs the reference to the original object?

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
    ['Trident','AOL browser (AOL desktop)','Win XP','6','A']
];

$('#example').dataTable( {
    columns: [
        { 
            "title": "Engine"
        },
        { "title": "Browser" },
        { "title": "Platform" },
        { "title": "Version", "className": "center" },
        { "title": "Grade", "className": "center" }
    ],

    data: dataSet
});

var table = $('#example').DataTable();

dataSet[0] = ['x','y','z','4','X'];

console.log(dataSet);

table.row(0).invalidate().draw();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y3fnvzad/13/

Am I better off using `table.row(0).data(['x','y','z','4','X']).draw()` in this case?

Comment: Yes, `table.row(0).data(['x','y','z','4','X']).draw()` is the correct way to update row data.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Thanks for confirming. Is it because datatable has lost the reference to the original item?

Comment: You're correct. `dataSet` is passed by value, therefore modifying the array elements afterwards doesn't have any effect. Please answer and accept your own answer, because you had it in your question.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Well, I wasn't sure about it, and you confirmed it. Please go ahead and add it as an answer so that I can award you the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, `table.row(0).data(['x','y','z','4','X']).draw()` is the proper way to update row data. See [row().data()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.data%28%29) for more details.

Variable `dataSet` is passed by value, therefore modifying the array elements afterwards doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

JS

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
 .....

table.fnUpdate(['x','y','z','4','X'], 0);
```

And you may also want to take a look at: 
[dataTable fnUpdate row with new value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862476/datatable-fnupdate-row-with-new-value)

Comment: Thanks, but `fnUpdate` is part of the legacy API. I think I'll stick with `row.data()`, since it's part of the current API.

Comment: Method `fnUpdate` would work, however it's for older version of DataTables 1.9.x. Code using new DataTables version should use [row().data()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.data%28%29) instead.