# Cannot update a row by TR id | DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

After numerous attempts and hours of looking on the datatables forum I came to the conclusion I just can't find my problem.

I want to dynamically update a row whenever the data is changed, everything works perfectly on serverside as well as client side, except for on thing, I can't figure out how to update a specific row by the ID of the TR.

```
$('.planning-table').dataTable().fnUpdate( 'Example update', 0, 2 );
```

As you can see, in my code I'm currently updating the first row and the third column with 'Example Data' in the cell. Works great.

But instead of the row number, I want to use the ID of that row since that is way easier in this case.
Deleting already works with this:

```
$('.planning-table').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(document.getElementById(entryID));
```

But using getElementById doesn't do the trick with fnUpdate since it expects a row number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862476/datatable-fnupdate-row-with-new-value

Comment: Have you tried `$('.planning-table').dataTable().fnUpdate( 'Example update', document.getElementById(entryID), 2 );`

Comment: Thanks @BG101!, Yeah @Gyrocode.com but that didn't work unfortunately! But I got it now I think :)

Comment: I have added an answer with an example that demonstrates that you can use `tr` node as row reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use `tr` element as row reference, see [`fnUpdate`](http://legacy.datatables.net/api#fnUpdate) for more information.

```
$('.planning-table').dataTable().fnUpdate( 
   'Example update', 
   document.getElementById(entryID), 
   2 
);
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fznenwjh/1/) for code and demonstration.